# Валидация нескольких форм на странице

Tags: php, yii2, фреймворк

Всем привет!
У меня есть страница с несколькими ActivForm формами на ней.
Дайте пожалуйста совет как лучше получать данные из этих форм в контроллере.
Если получение дынных будет выполнятся через один экшен, тогда придется определять через какую форму пришли данные(будет куча if'ов) чего хотелось бы избежать т.к. экшен получится довольно "толстым".

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   $model1 = MyForm1();
   $model2 = MyForm2();
   $model3 = MyForm3();

   $result = Yii::$app->request->post();

   //Этого очень хотелось бы избежать
   if (isset($result['form_1'])) {
        ...
   } elseif (isset($result['form_2'])) {
         ...
        return $this->render('index', ['form1' => $form1, 'form2' => $form2, 'form3' => $form3]);
   }
   ...
   return $this->render('index', ['form1' => $form1, 'form2' => $form2, 'form3' => $form3]);
 }
```

Если для каждой формы пилить свой экшен, тогда код будет практически полностью дублироваться:

```
public function actionForm1()
{
   $model1 = MyForm1();
   $model2 = MyForm2();
   $model3 = MyForm3();

   if ( $model1->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) ) {
       $model1->saveData();
   }

   return $this->render('index', ['form1' => $form1, 'form2' => $form2, 'form3' => $form3]);
}

public function actionForm2()
{
   $model1 = MyForm1();
   $model2 = MyForm2();
   $model3 = MyForm3();

   if ( $model2->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) ) {
       $model2->saveData();
   }

   return $this->render('index', ['form1' => $form1, 'form2' => $form2, 'form3' => $form3]);
}

public function actionForm3()
{
   $model1 = MyForm1();
   $model2 = MyForm2();
   $model3 = MyForm3();

   if ( $model3->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) ) {
       $model3->saveData();
   }

   return $this->render('index', ['form1' => $form1, 'form2' => $form2, 'form3' => $form3]);
}
```

Также есть мысль объединить все в одну форму но тогда возникнет проблема с валидацией, т.к. там очень много не связанных друг с другом данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы сами загнали себя в эту ловушку. Не используйте один action для 3-х форм - это же, очевидно, ошибка, лишняя сложность, ненужное увеличение кода. Нужно стремиться делать код как можно проще, прозрачнее, понятнее, а не наоборот. А вызовы дублируемого кода можно вынести в отдельные методы.

```
public function actionForm1()
{
   list($form1, $form2, $form3) = $this->initializateForms();

   $this->validateForm($form1);

   return $this->render('index', compact('form1', 'form2', 'form3'));
}

public function actionForm2()
{
   list($form1, $form2, $form3) = $this->initializateForms();

   $this->validateForm($form2);

   return $this->render('index', compact('form1', 'form2', 'form3'));
}

public function actionForm3()
{
   list($form1, $form2, $form3) = $this->initializateForms();

   $this->validateForm($form3);

   return $this->render('index', compact('form1', 'form2', 'form3'));
}

protected function initializateForms()
{
    return [
        new MyForm1(),
        new MyForm2(),
        new MyForm3(),
    ];
}

protected function validateForm($form)
{
    if ( $form->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) ) {
       $form->saveData();
   }
}
```

PS: Yii отлично умеет работать с формами через ajax из коробки и в данном случае, я бы реализовал валидацию, отправку форм именно через ajax.